# Django admin. Edit user and leave password unchanged

Tags: django, passwords, admin

I have my custom user model:

```
class RemoteUser(AbstractUser):

    class Meta:
        verbose_name= 'MyUser'
        verbose_name_plural = 'MyUsers'

    # Custom fields here...
```

How do I set up my user admin form to edit user details hiding the password?

```
class RemoteUserForm(UserCreationForm):
    # What do I put here?
```

Even if I exclude `password` from fields it keeps giving me `KeyError 'password1'`.

Comment: Why are you inheriting from UserCreationForm then?

Comment: You have to do this without  `UserCreationForm`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `ModelForm`, its very simple using that. You create a form class for editing user objects, in fields you can specifiy whichever you want to edit. Use this form in view to save the input data and use the context in template to complete the cycle.

**`Forms.py`**
    from django.contrib.auth.models import User

```
class EditUserForm(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = {'username'}
```

**`Views.py`**

```
def update_userprofile(request, pk):
    user = User.objects.get(pk=pk)
    user_form = EditUserForm(instance=user)
    if request.user.id == user.id:
        if request.method == "POST":
            user_form = EditUserForm(request.POST, instance=user)
            if user_form.is_valid():
                created_user = user_form.save(commit=False)
                return redirect('someview') #wherever you want

        return render(request, "app_name/update_userprofile.html", {
            "noodle": pk,
            "noodle_form": user_form,}
    else:
        raise PermissionDenied
```

**`Update_userprofile.html`**

```
<form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %} {{ noodle_form.as_p }}
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```